# Architectural pattern for multiple Python applications with shared database

Tags: python, design-patterns, architecture, data-analysis

The project consists of two applications in Python with a single shared database:

- Application A: performs preprocessing of raw data and stores it in the database;
- Application B: performs data analysis techniques on the already populated database.

[image]

What should be the right architectural pattern for such a context?

Also, so far I have been using MongoDB and Flask to populate the database but I don't know if it would be suitable as a choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about a database access pattern, you can always use ORMs (Object relational mappers). An object-relational mapper (ORM) is a code library that automates the transfer of data stored in relational database tables into objects that are more commonly used in application code.

You can learn more about ORM in here. https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html

I believe this would be better suited for python than the DAO pattern we use in java. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm